# How to recover 100GB missing from macOS after an update?

Tags: macos, backup, migration

**Background:** I recently upgraded my system to El Capitan. On the first run of the new operating system I ran more updates from the App Store that required a restart. However, while updating, it appeared to be hanging and my computer was getting very hot. So I decided to hard restart the computer. Then I let the installation run again with no issue. I don't know if restarting my computer while updating software caused me to lose about 100GB of data from my mac, but about 80GB were missing from the User Library folder. I know this because I have a backup of my old system (pre-El Capitan) to compare to. So far everything seems to work fine...

**The question is:** Is it worth checking to find out which files/folders are missing and somehow replace them, or better to wipe my hard drive, clone my old system backup to my cleaned hard drive, and upgrade again to El Capitan.

Possible solutions I've come to:

- Use migration assistant to transfer my user accounts, my applications, and my "other files" to my new El Capitan system.
- Find a way to compare what files are missing from my old system backup and my El Capitan system, and bring those over in some automated process...maybe by using the `ditto` command?

Comment: The "missing" files are likely cache and other temporary files. An OS update does not touch user files and unless you already had a problem with your disk (soft or hard errors that perhaps went unnoticed). I would be tempted to make or keep a backup of the old system and use it only when you find files that went missing.

Comment: I did have force my system to hard shutdown when Firefox wouldn't close no matter how many ways I tried to force quit it.